# Retrieve state of Windows 10 Power mode slider

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, battery-saver

Is there any API to retrieve a state of Windows 10 Power mode slider?

[image]

I was looking at [`Windows.System.Power` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power). But [`PowerManager` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power.powermanager) seem to provide only an immediate state of the power system, but not user preferences set by the slider.

The slider also exists somehow in parallel with previous "power plan" settings. It does not seem that the slider state is reflected directly in [`Win32_PowerPlan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/powerwmiprov/win32-powerplan) or [`PowerGetActiveScheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powersetting/nf-powersetting-powergetactivescheme) or `powercfg /getactivescheme`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the position of the slider, and the registry key:`HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes\ActiveOverlayAc/DcPowerScheme` will also change.
ActiveOverlayAcPowerScheme is for non-battery powered and ActiveOverlayDcPowerScheme is for battery powered.
However, Starting with Windows release 1903 the slider is available for AC only devices as an OEM opt-in feature.
The values of the key `ActiveOverlayAcPowerScheme` and the corresponding slider modes are as follows:

Better Battery      {961CC777-2547-4F9D-8174-7D86181b8A7A}

Better Performance  {381B4222-F694-41F0-9685-FF5BB260DF2E}

Best Performance    {DED574B5-45A0-4F42-8737-46345C09C238}

the `ActivePowerScheme` will be overlaid with `ActiveOverlayAcPowerScheme`.
you can retrieve the key value to get the slider mode.

Comment: Thanks. -- Just that for "Better Performance" I actually get `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`

Comment: Because that's the default performance, and don't need to be overlay